# Merge Vector Layers fails in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, merge

I'm trying to merge two vector layer as part of a graphic model but get an error:

> OBJECTID field in layer layer1 has different data type than in other
>   layers (Integer64 instead of Real) Execution failed after 0.06 seconds

And both layers have a field called OBJECTID with different data types. I don't care about the attributes I just need the geometries. Isn't there a way of telling merge to ignore the attributes?

I would rather not have to drop/rename all fields prior to merge (I have a lot of layers, not only these two with many fields to drop). Maybe there is a QGIS equivalent of ArcGIS MakeFeatureLayer to disable fields prior to merging.

[image: example]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another solution that may be used particularly in the Processing Modeler.

Let's assume there are two polygon layers *'layer_1'* and *'layer_2'* with its corresponding attribute tables accordingly, see image below.

[image: input]

With the following model, it is possible to merge two vector layers with no attributes only their geometries.

[image: model]

The output with its Attribute table will look as following

[image: output]

---

***Note:***

1. On the last image, attributes were added by default
2. For both SQL queries use these settings

   [image: sql]

Comment: Nice, didnt know `Execute SQL` works on "non-SQL"-inputs. `select geometry from input1
union
select geometry from input2 union ...` did the trick

Comment: yes, this can be done also...I thought that merge is a mandatory step in your workflow.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest some PyQGIS but not sure if it corresponds to your requirements

```py
layer_1 = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('unit_1')[0]
layer_1_new = processing.run('qgis:deletecolumn',
    {'INPUT': layer_1,
    'COLUMN': ['id', 'length'], #here you will need to specify all the columns that have to be erased for the first layer
    'OUTPUT': "memory:"}
)["OUTPUT"]

layer_2 = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('unit_2')[0]
layer_2_new = processing.run('qgis:deletecolumn',
    {'INPUT': layer_2,
    'COLUMN': ['id'], #here you will need to specify all the columns that have to be erased for the second layer
    'OUTPUT': "memory:"}
)["OUTPUT"]

layer_merged = processing.run('qgis:mergevectorlayers',
    {'CRS': 'EPSG:***', #use a proper EPSG
    'LAYERS': [layer_2_new, layer_1_new],
    'OUTPUT': 'memory:'}
)['OUTPUT']

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer_merged)
```

Answer (score 0):

I could try with the **Promote to the multipart option** as shown in the video below:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vdqx4C0C3Mc&t=58s&ab_channel=MariuszKrukar