# Virtual Layer from SQL query is extremely slow

Tags: qgis, sql, performance, virtual-layer

I have two layers, one is a grid of circles and the other is all Census Block Groups (CBG) in the state of Florida. I created a Virtual Layer out of this code

```sql
SELECT CirclesFlorida.name, group_concat(cbgFl.FIPS)
FROM CirclesFlorida
LEFT JOIN cbgFl ON ST_Intersects(circlesFlorida.geometry, cbgFl.geometry)
GROUP BY circlesflorida.name
```

The purpose is for each circle to have a data column which lists every CBG that falls in that circle.

Is there a faster way to do this? Maybe DB Manager? Currently the query takes 20 minutes to run and another 5 minutes to just open the attribute table of the Virtual Layer.

Comment: the db manager sql interface will use a sqlite database on the back-end to do the processing... I would try it out. I don't know if the sql layer is doing the same.

Comment: As an alternative try to construct a model in the Graphical Modeler, it can also work with SQL queries, see this https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/360796/99589.

Comment: Otherwise you may try running the Virtual Layer via Python console, check this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/227203/creating-new-virtual-layer-programmatically-in-qgis

Comment: @DPSSpatial the sqlite doesn't recognize the ".geometry" attribute as a column. Is it written in a different kind of SQL? How would I write it?

Comment: https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#use-of-indexes

Comment: The reason to use a virtual layer is so that the layer will update as the underlying data changes. If you don't care about that, you can use the Execute SQL tool (there are actually two - native and GDAL) from the Processing Toolbox.

Comment: Try to use `_searchframe_` in your query! This helped me: https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/qgis-developer/2021-May/063582.html